# creating a php function from multiple expressions

Tags: php, function

I want to create a function that does a couple of things. I know how to do all of these things independently but when i've been trying to put them all in a function, i've been running into a few problems...suggestions?

Thanks!!

I want a function that takes a sentence string and makes it into an argument and then reports the length number of words in the string. (So, first how do I turn:

```
    $wordcount = str_word_count();
```

into a function?)

I want the funcion to replace the words cat and dog with meow and bark (if they are in the string)... So how do I add this to my function:

```
    $words = array('cat', 'dog');
    $newWords = str_ireplace($words, 'meow', 'bark');
```

Then, i want the new string (with the replaced words) returned as an array and if cat and dog aren't in the string, then I just want "You have no pets" to be displayed.

I've only been able to accomplish this so far with individual expressions, and not in a function so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this homework?  Also, if you look through the PHP docs for [array](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) and [string](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) functions, I think you'll find some tools that you can use...

Comment: Start from here http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: not homework...I'm just actually trying to learn about functions. Every resource i've found on functions seems so vague to me. I was kind of looking to see if someone could easily explain how to turn what I have into a function because it seems (to me anyway) like there should be a way to take existing stuff and turn it into a function...

Comment: Have you read the PHP doc about functions linked above?  What is it that you have a hard-time understanding?  Do you know any other programming languages?  Creating a PHP function is not unlike creating one in C, C++, Java, C#, etc.

Answer (score 0):

well str_word_count() is already a function.

since you want two separate return values, you may want to consider leaving this as two separate functions, as this would help uphold the single responsibility principle.

as for your second set of expressions, this seems fairly straightforwardly turned into a function like so:

```
function my_function($input) {
   $search = array('meow', 'bark');
   $replace = array('cat', 'dog');
   $output = str_ireplace($search, $replace, $input, $replace_count);
   if ($replace_count === 0) {
      return false;
   } else {
      return explode(' ', $output);
   }
}
```

and to use the function:

```
$result = my_function($input_string);
if ($result === false) {
   echo 'You have no pets';
} else {
   var_dump($result);
}
```

Comment: That's why I kind of don't prefer PHP. For a certain condition you are returning a boolean value and for another condition, an array :-). But it is a good answer, +1.

Comment: @Sayem Ahmed it's not PHP's fault. It's the requirements set forth from the developer. This should actually be two separate functions. one that checks for the presence of the match elements, and another that processes the string. PHP shouldn't be blamed for how people want to use it. freedom isn't a bad thing if you follow good practices.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your help @dqhendricks! As I'm new to this whole function thing, if there is a better way to achieve what i'm looking to do, i'm more than open to suggestions! In fact, I would be grateful for any opinions/comments that can help.

Comment: @Ginny agile development principles would suggest that you should have one responsibility per function, basically meaning each function should have one type of return value. you might want to read about agile development and jump straight into object oriented programming as soon as you get comfortable.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not comfortable at all with functions (which is a shame) because up until this point I was understanding PHP pretty well. Writing original code is not really my strongest skill (i know, missing the whole point...lol) but i'm really only able to learn by looking at completed code and then figuring out how to change it to make it something I need. With the code you provided, what should i do to get the input to work with it? Everything I just tried didn’t work which only discouraged me even more! Is it normal to feel like you want to breakdown and cry when working with php functions?

Comment: @Ginny you may want to buy a book or two. very helpful to get started.

Comment: Sad thing is, I have 3 books! I guess i'm just going to call it and give up on ever figuring this out...thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ginny dont give up. you use functions all the time already; the ones built into php. now you just have to figure out how to create and use your own. you define a function as i showed above. each functioncan take inputs (aka arguments) and can have a return value defined by the return keyword. $output = funtion_name($input_arguments)